# Using Rasterize Tool (vector to raster) of QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, vector, qgis-2, rasterization

I am using QGIS 2.18.28.

I am trying to convert a vector file into a raster using the rasterize tool however it us just producing a back block of a single value. I am rather confused as I have used this tool on another shapefile in the same project and it has worked perfectly.

The first screen shot is of the shape files in which i want to convert to raster (Nodes). I have included the attributes table in the screen shot.

The second screen shot is the input in which I used in the tool.

The the third screen shot is the output.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please consider upgrading to the latest LTR.

Comment: If you change the Raster type from `float32` to `integer`, will it solve the problem?

Comment: I have tried each of the raster type options and have produced the same output

Comment: Hello - similar situation here.  I have a raster of tree canopy (nlcd_2016...) and a vector of post 2016 HazFuels treatment areas.  I'm trying to rasterize the latter into a grid of 1s (no treatment) and  0.45 (treatment) with the intent of multiplying the nlcd raster by the rasterized HazFuels treatment areas to crudely express the change in tree canopy since 2016.   I've been hacking at this all day, and can't get anything better than a raster of a constant value or a raster of 0.45 and 'no data' .   What works? [link](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AmMT5E-2wBxLh0NvzJtNxQPHmuuG?e=aM0Mgl)

Comment: Try with smaller pixel size. What the result will be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had a similar issue.

changed burn-in value to 1
(it was set to 0)
problem solved